# Indentation in text of email body

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email

What I intend on doing is using Google Apps Script to send an email using the MailApp.sendEmail. The code I have right now is

```
      var recipientsTO = emailOne + "," + emailTwo;
      var subject = "subject";
      var message = "Dear so and so,"<br><br>Congratulations! A brief summary is provided
                     below.<br><br><h3 style='text-decoration: underline;'>"
+                    Name+"</h3>Contact: "+contact+"<br>Description: "+Description;
              MailApp.sendEmail(
                recipientsTO,
                subject,
                "", { 
                  htmlBody: message,
                  name: 'Name of Sender',
                });
```

The email body should look like this

> Dear so and so,
>
> Congratulations! A brief summary is provided below.
>
> **Name**(Underlined)
>
> Contact : Contact
>
> Description : Description

is there a way to change it to

> (INDENTED)**Name**(Underlined)
>
> (INDENTED)Contact : Contact
>
> (INDENTED)Description : Description

Is there a specific method on Google Apps Script or is it HTML/CSS I have to play around with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to send an HTML email, you can wrap each line in a div and add some margin using CSS. This will appear to the reader as indented text.

You modified code will look like this

```
  var recipientsTO = emailOne + "," + emailTwo;
  var subject = "subject";
  var message = 'Dear so and so,"<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;">Congratulations! A brief summary is provided below.</div>'
                +'<br><br><div style="margin-left:40px;"><h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Name:'+name+'</h3></div>'
                +'<div style="margin-left:40px;">Contact: '+contact+'</div><br>'
                +'<div style="margin-left:40px;">Description: '+description+'</div>';
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    recipientsTO,
    subject,
    "", 
    { 
      htmlBody: message,
      name: 'Name of Sender',
    });
```

Comment: thanks a bunch. I totally forgot about putting it in divs.

Answer (score 0):

Waqar's method works; but to add on a potentially cleaner/ easier strategy:

You can create your HTML email in a HTML file within the GAS environment. This will rest as a tab on the left. You can create this using File > New > HTML file.

You can then call your HTML body (named "Email Template") in the script like so:

```
var emailBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Email Template").getContent();
```

You can call this variable in the email sender or write it straight into the script. I call the variable in the sender. `emailTag` is a list of users to send to retrieved from the sheet.

```
   function emailCreator() {
      var emailTag = sheet.getRange(range).getValue();
      var emailSubject = "subject";
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailTag,
        subject: emailSubject,
        htmlBody: emailBody,
      });
    }
```